# Has anyone used Node.JS to update MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express

I use AJAX to "GET" data into my Node Client, but I cant seem to figure out how to "POST" that data to MySQL.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql npm module: `npm install mysql`

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost'
    user: 'youruser'
    password: 'yourpassword' 
    database: 'yourdb'
});

pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    connection.query('INSERT INTO tbl_name (col1,col2) VALUES(' + theValueYouGotFromAjax + ',' + anotherValue + ')' + '\'', function (err, result) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            console.log('Created ' + result.affectedRows + ' rows');
            connection.release();
            console.log('Connection returned to pool.');
});
```

Check module documentation: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/tree/v0.9